# Interpreting an abstract syntax graph efficiently

Tags: haskell, graph, abstract-syntax-tree, data-reify

Take a minimal language (apparently called Hutton's Razor):

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-methods #-}

data Expr =
    Lit Int
  | Add Expr Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Num Expr where
  fromInteger = Lit . fromInteger
  (+)         = Add

tree 0 = 1
tree n =
  let shared = tree (n - 1)
  in  shared + shared
```

If we just run `tree 30` in GHCi, the type will default to `Integer` and we'll get an immediate answer as recursive computations of `tree` are shared.  But if we run `tree 30 :: Expr`, we get an enormous syntax tree as the sharing provided by Haskell's `let` doesn't transfer to expressions in the embedded language.

The `data-reify` library can be used to observe any *implicit* sharing that might be present in an expression.  We can add some machinery to enable that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Reify

data ExprF e =
    LitF Int
  | AddF e e
  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

instance MuRef Expr where
  type DeRef Expr = ExprF
  mapDeRef f (Add e0 e1) = Add <$> f e0 <*> f e1
  mapDeRef _ (Lit d)     = pure (LitF d)
```

And applying the `reifyGraph` function to an expression like `tree 30 :: Expr` now returns a graph where sharing is explicit.  Here's a more digestible example:

```
> reifyGraph (tree 2 :: Expr)
let [(1,AddF 2 2),(2,AddF 3 3),(3,LitF 1)] in 1
```

So now I'm interested in interpreting an abstract syntax *graph* rather than an abstract syntax *tree*.

A naive `evalGraph` function eliminates sharing by interpreting it as if it were a tree:

```
evalGraph (Graph env r) = go r where
  go j = case lookup j env of
    Just (AddF a b) -> go a + go b
    Just (LitF d)   -> d
    Nothing         -> 0
```

as can be verified by trying

```
> evalGraph <$> reifyGraph (tree 50 :: Expr)
```

Not being all that experienced in this sort of thing, I have found it surprisingly difficult to come up with an simple and efficient implementation of `evalGraph`.

[Oliveira and Löh](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/ASGDSL.pdf) provide an example in which a graph like this is used to build an expression in a proxy language where sharing is explicit (which can then just be evaluated in that setting), but it seems like that's an unnecessarily heavyweight approach to take if I just want to consume the graph immediately.

What is the best approach to evaluate this type of graph while preserving its sharing?

### Edit:

Memoization à la `Data.StableMemo` handles everything perfectly right from the get-go, but given some syntax in a DAG structure (for whatever reason), I think that the topological sort + memoization is the right way to go here.

Here's a quick/hacky graph-based evaluator:

```
import Data.Graph
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO.Unsafe

graphEval :: Expr -> Int
graphEval expr = consume reified where
  reified = unsafePerformIO (toGraph <$> reifyGraph expr)
  toGraph (Reify.Graph env _) = graphFromEdges . map toNode $ env
  toNode (j, AddF a b) = (AddF a b, j, [a, b])
  toNode (j, LitF d)   = (LitF d, j, [])

consume :: Eq a => (Graph, Vertex -> (ExprF a, a, b), c) -> Int
consume (g, vmap, _) = go (reverse . topSort $ g) [] where
  go [] acc = snd $ head acc
  go (v:vs) acc =
    let nacc = evalNode (vmap v) acc : acc
    in  go vs nacc

evalNode :: Eq a => (ExprF a, b, c) -> [(a, Int)] -> (b, Int)
evalNode (LitF d, k, _)   _ = (k, d)
evalNode (AddF a b, k, _) l =
  let v = fromJust ((+) <$> lookup a l <*> lookup b l)
  in  (k, v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your graph is a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), the problem is quite simple:

1. Order nodes topologically
2. Evaluate in order, looking up values as you go.

It would work like this for your example:

Reverse the nodes to:

```
[(3,LitF 1),(2,AddF 3 3),(1,AddF 2 2)]
```

Then evaluate them in order, looking up the previous values:

```
[1,2,4]
```

Comment: It may be natural to fuse the two steps; for example, fusing a DFS-based topological sort with the evaluation step results in a memoized version of the naive algorithm. (I don't actually know Haskell, so I'm not sure whether I'm interpreting things correctly, but this is what it looks like to me.)

Answer (score 7):

You need not give up on the tree approach yet. Sharing does indeed occur, the problem is just that function calls are not memoized even over shared subexpressions.

You can solve this quite easily by using identity based memoization in your eval function.

```
eval = go
 where go = memo eval'
       eval' (Lit i) = i
       eval' (Add e1 e2) = go e1 + go e2
```

I tested this using the [stable-memo package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stable-memo) and it seems to work well.